# SQLalchemy keyword argument equivalent of `Column('id', String, Enum(("foo", "bar")))`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm looking at [https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Identity) and [https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.**init**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.__init__), but I can't see what the equivalent would be for the following **attempt**:

```py
Column(name='id', type_=String, server_default=Enum(("foo", "bar")))
```

I tried `default=server_default=Enum(("foo", "bar"))` but received the following error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Argument 'arg' is expected to be one of type '<class 'str'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ClauseElement'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause'>', got '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Enum'>'
```

Am I meant to use https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.DefaultClause or `sqlalchemy.schema.DefaultGenerator` or is it not meant to be a default/equivalent at all?

Comment: "is it not meant to be a default=/equivalent at all?" - This. It is used to define the *type* of the column, not the default *value* for the column.

Comment: Isn't `String` the `type_`?

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy can automatically store Enum values as strings if the backend database does not have a native ENUM type. From the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum):

> The `Enum` type will make use of the backend’s native “ENUM” type if one is available; otherwise, it uses a VARCHAR datatype.

So, for a database like SQLite that does not have a native ENUM type, the column `type_` is still declared as `Enum`:

```py
import enum
from sqlalchemy import Column, Enum, Integer, MetaData, Table, create_engine, insert, select


class SexEnum(enum.Enum):
    female = "F"
    male = "M"


engine = create_engine("sqlite://")

tbl = Table(
    "tbl",
    MetaData(),
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("sex", Enum(SexEnum, create_constraint=True, name="sex_enum")),
)
engine.echo = True
tbl.create(engine)
"""
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    sex VARCHAR(6), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    CONSTRAINT sex_enum CHECK (sex IN ('female', 'male'))
)
"""

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(insert(tbl), dict(sex=SexEnum.male))
"""
INSERT INTO tbl (sex) VALUES (?)
[generated in 0.00033s] ('male',)
"""

with engine.begin() as conn:
    print(conn.execute(select(tbl)).all())
    # [(1, <SexEnum.male: 'M'>)]
```